# RN4020 BLE module authentication without I/O Capabilities and mysterious datasheet

Tags: datasheet, microchip, bluetooth-low-energy

I'm trying to activate authentication for my RN4020 Bluetooth module in a way I dont have to enter PIN or Passcode during this process because my RN4020 wont have any displays or keyboards where to display or enter PIN.

This is what [datasheet(table 2-7, page 29)](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70005191B.pdf) says about it

> `SR,<hex32>`
>
> This command sets the supported features of current RN4020
>   module. The input  parameter is a 32-bit bitmap that indicates
>   features to be supported.

`Auto Advertise 0x20000000`

`Enable Authentication 0x00400000`

`I/O Capabilities 0x000E0000`. I/O capability of the module. Only useful if the Enable Authentication bit is set.

- ‘b000 = Display Only
- ‘b001 = Display Yes/No
- ‘b010 = Keyboard Only
- ‘b011 = No Input, no output
- ‘b100 = Keyboard Display

This is already where the mystery starts because its not said in the datasheet where the (I suppose) binary values for these I/O capabilities are supposed to be in this hex32 number.

I read [here about disabling pin when making authentication(pairing) process](http://www.microchip.com/forums/m857600.aspx)

> First, disable authentication, so that RN4020 won't ask for a Pin
>   code. For the parameter of command "SR", bit 0x00400000 should be
>   cleared.

which is already weird because why would I disable authentication if I'm trying to do it and I/O capabilities are working only if the Enable Authentication bit is set. And next...

> On the other hand, declare that RN4020 has no I/O capability, so the
>   peer device won't ask Keyboard I/O authentication. For the parameter
>   of command "SR", the 3 bits 0x000E0000 should be set to 0x00060000 to
>   indicate RN4020 has no I/O capability.

What the number 6 is standing for? And again if authentication is disabled by disabling bits 0x00400000 then these 0x000E0000 I/O capabilities are not supposed to work at all. But mystery is that when I use `SR,20060000` it actually works and I can bond devices without using PIN. Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The I/O capabilities bitmask value is 0x000E0000 and the binary values you list are the 3 MSBs in the "E".

I have used these modes:
Display only - the RN4020 UART outputs a 6-digit passcode which must be entered in the connecting device.
Keyboard only - the connecting device is sent a passcode which must be entered on an input device connected to the RN4020.

I also tried No input, no output and was unsuccessful in connecting.  I haven't figured out how to store a fixed PIN that the connecting device must enter.

Comment: Ohh, tnx a lot man it makes sense - If I want to specify `b011 = No Input, no output` in place of `E` I have to use `b0110` which is 6 in hex. I have already switched to Bluetooth Classic because of not being able to scan for **direct** advertisement post Android 6 but this will be very helpful to other people :)